# PHP inet_ntop() is acting differently on real VPS

Tags: php

I deployed my application on a VPS and It works fine expect the `inet_ntop()` function. On my local web server it's working fine with no error message.

I store the IP addresses in a `binary(16)` column. Before I would store them into the database I convert them. My last login IP is: `4e43b7`, in binary numbers: `00110100 01100101 00110100 00110011 01100010 00110111` and the readable format: `78.92.67.183`. So it run with a warning message on the VPS: `Warning: inet_ntop(): Invalid in_addr value in home/...`

What's wrong? According to the PHP doc the function works on PHP 5.1 or higher and a VPS has 5.5, but I am using 5.6. Can version differences cause problem? This line causes the warning:

```
$ip = inet_ntop($datas['ip_address'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-varbinary.html):

> When BINARY values are stored, they are right-padded with the pad value to the specified length. The pad value is 0x00 (the zero byte).

so you're not pulling out a 32bit IPv4 address. You're pulling out an 16x8bit = 128bit value, and feeding that to inet_ntop().

Comment: Oh, and this value is not valid to the inet_ntop() function. But this binary number has 6 octet. It should have 5, the IPv4 address and the zero byte. And How can it work with 127.0.0.1 or localhost?

Comment: `localhost` is a hostname, not an ip address. it's almost always mapped to 127.0.0.1, which IS an ip, and would simply be `01111111 00000000 00000000 00000001`

Answer (score 1):

As Marc B noted, your BINARY column is being right-padded with zeroes which is then throwing off your decoding. There's not a super good way of handling this, particularly within just MySQL.

However, IPv6 has a built-in method of encapsulating IPv4 addresses, [6to4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4). Using this you can store v4 and v6 addresses side-by-side in a way that's maintainable and easy to deal with.

```
function fourToSix($addr) {
    $haddr = str_pad(dechex(ip2long($addr)), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $v6 = sprintf('2002:%s::', implode(':', str_split($haddr, 2)));
    return $v6;
}

function sixToFour($addr) {
    return long2ip(hexdec(implode('', array_slice(explode(':', $addr), 1, 4))));
}

function isSixToFour($addr) {
    return explode(':', $addr)[0] == '2002';
}

$v4 = '10.1.2.3';
$v6 = '2002:0a:01:02:03::';
var_dump(
    fourToSix($v4),
    isSixToFour($v6),
    sixToFour($v6),
    bin2hex(inet_pton($v6))
);
```

Output:

```
string(18) "2002:0a:01:02:03::"
bool(true)
string(8) "10.1.2.3"
string(32) "2002000a000100020003000000000000"
```

### edit

Example store:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table (id, addr) VALUES(?, ?);');
// convert IP if it is v4
if( ip2long($ip_addr) !== false ) {
    $ip_addr = fourToSix($ip_addr);
}
$stmt->execute(1, inet_pton($ip_addr));
```

Example retrieve:

```
$addr_raw = $dbh->query('SELECT addr FROM table WHERE id=1')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['addr'];

$addr_str = inet_ntop($addr_raw);
if( isSixToFour($addr_str) ) {
    printf("IPv4 address is: %s\n", sixToFour($addr_str));
} else {
    printf("IPv6 address is: %s\n", $addr_str);
}
```

Comment: I see. It helps me a lot, but I still dont't know how to fix the zero byte padding. Change it to varchar type?

Comment: @ampika if you store everything as IPv6 addresses, with v4 encapsulated with 6to4, you don't have to worry about the padding *at all*. See updated answer.

Comment: So when I want to convert back to the retried IP, I got this: "2002:7f:0:0:1::" instead of this `2002:7f:00:00:01::` but if I don't store them in the database your method works fine. It is confusing me. :/